# Vlookup data in certain external excel file using a function

Tags: vba, excel

I use a lot of Vlookup to find prices in a certain file (c:/pricelist.xlsx), using the product code. I would like to simplify it by creating a new VBA function, but it does not work.

```
Function findprice(codes)

Dim price
Dim pricebook As Workbook
Dim pricesheet As Worksheet
Dim pricerange As Range
Dim coderange As Range

Set pricebook = Workbooks("c:\info\pricelist.xlsx")
Set pricesheet = pricebook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Set pricerange = pricesheet.Range("FF1:FF20000")
Set coderange = pricesheet.Range("H1:H20000")


findprice = Application.Index(pricerange, Application.Match(codes, coderange, 0))


End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I just started to learn VBA

Comment: What does doesn't work mean please?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for everyone's help! I got "#VALUE" error when using the findprice function I created.

Comment: Regrading why am I doing this while VLookup can do it: I would like to simplify the process, so that I don't need to jump between two files everytime and choose the right range to look for the price. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure since your question didn't include any sample data or explanation of what/why you're trying to do, but I suspect you're over-complicating this is a few ways.

- You don't need a custom function to call a worksheet function from the worksheet.  Just use the worksheet functions instead.
- In this case `VLookup` is easier and saves a step (as you suggested in your title.)
- Instead of referring to huge ranges of two cells, just refer to the whole columns.
- Referring to cells in another Excel file is just like any other formula that refers to another file.  (More infor [here](https://support.office.com/article/create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-c98d1803-dd75-4668-ac6a-d7cca2a9b95f))

---

You should be able to use something like this on the worksheet:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,'c:\info\pricelist.xlsx'!$H:$FF,155,FALSE)
```

...where `A1` is the value to match (ie., `codes`).

If you *do* need this is VBA for some reason, it's easy to adapt just like your sample function.

---

### More Information:

- Office Support : [**Create or change a cell reference**](https://support.office.com/article/create-or-change-a-cell-reference-c7b8b95d-c594-4488-947e-c835903cebaa)
- Office Support : [**Create an external reference (link) to a cell range in another workbook**](https://support.office.com/article/create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-c98d1803-dd75-4668-ac6a-d7cca2a9b95f)

Comment: Hi Thanks! I know I can do it using Vlookup, just want to save some effort of going between different files and ranges everytime!